# Parameterizing a SQL Server connection String in SSIS

Tags: ssis, connection-string

I'm parametrizing a SQL Server connection string in SSIS.

The method I'm using is using project parameters for the database name, username and password, and building up the connection string in the expressions section of the connection, see below.

Is this a legitimate way to parameterize a connection string in SSIS, or can these be overwritten by other connection values?

For example, if I click on the connection and view its properties, it is definitely not using the project parameters. Could these overwrite the connection string I am constructing?

[image]

```
"Data Source=" +  @[$Project::SourceServer]  + 
";User ID=" +  @[$Project::SqlServerUsername] + 
";Initial Catalog="  + @[$Project::SourceDatabase] + 
";Password="  +  @[$Project::SqlServerPassword] + 
";Provider=MSOLEDBSQL19.1;Persist Security Info=True;Auto Translate=False;Connect Timeout=120;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=yes;"
```